# Bubblesort Array Ascending

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, methods

I have a data file that I need to sort the information by Make&&Model of vehicle. My bubblesort doesn't work, can you help me to fix my problem, please ? Thank you very much!
P.S. I can't have extra methods :( if I remove getMake() method, it works but && getModel doesn't work at all :(

```
    public static void sortByVehicleMakeModel(Vehicle[] vehicles) {
        for(int y = 0; y < vehicles.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0 ; x < vehicles.length - 1 ; x++){
                if((vehicles[x].getMake().compareToIgnoreCase(vehicles[x+1].getMake()) > 0) && (vehicles[x].getModel().compareToIgnoreCase(vehicles[x+1].getModel()) > 0)) {    
                    swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
                }           
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < vehicles.length - 1; x++){
            System.out.println(vehicles[x].getMake());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's going wrong? Could you give a stacktrace if it's throwing errors, or describe the faulty output it's giving?

Comment: @awolfe91 no there is no error, it just doesn't sort!!!

Comment: It doesn't work because you only swap them if the model **AND** make are different.  You need to take into account when the _make_ is the same, but the _model_ is different.  See my answer...

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps to compare two vehicles:

- compare the *make* of the two vehicles
- if they're **not** equal, return the result of the comparison
- if they **are** equal, compare the *model* and return the result

You should replace the code in your *if statement* with a method that compares two Vehicles using the logic described above.

Something like this:

```
if (compareVehicles(vehicles[x], vehicles[x + 1]) > 0) {
    swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
}
```

---

To do this the correct way, you should make *Vehicle* implement *Comparable*.

That way you can put the above logic in your *compareTo* method.

This will allow you to simply do this:

```
if (vehicles[x].compareTo(vehicles[x + 1]) > 0) {
    swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
}
```

Here's a simple example of how to implement Comparable:

```
class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle> {
    private String make;
    private String model;

    public int compareTo(Vehicle other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        int compareVal = make.compareToIgnoreCase(other.make);
        if (compareVal == 0) {
            return model.compareToIgnoreCase(other.model);
        }
        else {
            return compareVal;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Ok... since it's been a few days, I'll just show you how to do it.

```
public static void sortVehicles(Vehicle[] vehicles) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.length - 1; i++) {
        Vehicle curr = vehicles[i];
        Vehicle next = vehicles[i + 1];
        String currMake = curr.getMake();
        String nextMake = next.getMake();
        int compareVal = currMake.compareToIgnoreCase(nextMake);
        // if the makes are the same, we need to compare the models
        if (compareVal == 0) {
            String currModel = curr.getModel();
            String nextModel = next.getModel();
            compareVal = currModel.compareToIgnoreCase(nextModel);
        }
        if (compareVal > 0) {
            swap(vehicles, i, i + 1);
        }
    }

    for (Vehicle v : vehicles) {
        System.out.println(v.getMake());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i just realized that i can't have extra method :( how can I do all in one?

Comment: @Dani - It shouldn't matter whether the code is in a method or not.  Just use the logic above to compare two Vehicles and store the result of the comparison as an int.  Then you can check whether the int is greater than zero in your _if statement_. Hint: use the logic in the _compareTo_ method above to set the value of your int.

Comment: I tried, but didn't work :(

Comment: @Dani - Feel free to edit your question to include your current code.  I'd be happy to take a look and offer some suggestions.  If you're getting errors or exceptions, it would help to describe them.

Comment: public int compareTo(Vehicle other) {
2
   int val = make.compareToIgnoreCase(other.make);
3
   if(val != 0)
4
        return val;
5
 
6
    return model.compareToIgnoreCase(other,model);
7
}

Answer (score 2):

Just to improve the performance(I realize for the comparison logic, @jahroy is right). I think the code of the second loop should be as below in your case:
**x < vehicles.length - y -1**

```
    for(int y = 0; y < vehicles.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < vehicles.length - y -1 ; x++){
            if((vehicles[x].getMake().compareToIgnoreCase(vehicles[x+1].getMake()) > 0) && (vehicles[x].getModel().compareToIgnoreCase(vehicles[x+1].getModel()) > 0)) {    
                swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but didn't change it :(

Answer (score 0):

here is how i fixed it:

```
public static void sortByVehicleMakeModel(Vehicle[] vehicles) {


    for(int y = 0; y < vehicles.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < vehicles.length - 1 ; x++){
            boolean compare1 = (vehicles[x].getMake().compareToIgnoreCase(vehicles[x+1].getMake()) > 0);

        if (compare1){
            swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);

        }       

    }           
}
```

Comment: This will not work for cars with the same make and different models.

Comment: There is no need to have two loops.  You never use the variable `y`.  If you have 20 vehicles, your current code will run 19 extra times for no reason.  It will do all the work when `y = 0`, then it will run 19 more times doing nothing (but wasting time and energy).

Comment: Okay guys calm down, this worked perfectly fine with no problem :) thank you for your attention

Comment: There is no way this code works correctly.