# Produce sorted arraylist from unsorted arraylist in 1 interation?

Tags: java

Say I have arraylist `A` and to compare 2 objects of `A` I do `a.getDistanceFromPlayer() < b.getDistanceFromPlayer()`.

I want to now have list `B` which will have all of `A`'s objects, but sorted where the first object is closest to player, and last object is furthest.

What might be the fastest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `closes to player` - which player?

Comment: The distances are already computed, the compare is just compare float A to float B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have A implement Comparable and then define the method compareTo(Object other) like so:

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {
  if( this.getDistanceFromPlayer() < other.getDistanceFromPlayer() ) {
      return -1;
  } else if( this.getDistanceFromPlayer() > other.getDistanceFromPlayer())  {
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now you can call Collections.sort() on your list of objects

Answer (score 2):

You should make your class implement *[Comparabl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)e*.

Then you can use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to sort your List.

If you want a sorted List **AND** an unsorted List, you'll have to make a copy.

---

Another option is to create a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

If you read the [documentation for Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), you'll see it has two *sort* methods.

One bases the sort on the objects' *compareTo* method (ie their "*natural order*").

The other bases the sort on a Comparator that is passed as the second argument.

---

Here's a link to another question that provides an example implementation of Comparable:

- [Example implementation of Comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13576577/778118)

Comment: How might I implement comparable?

Comment: It's a very simple interface to implement.  It only has one method, _compareTo_ which compares an object to another instance of the same type.  It returns an int based on the comparison.  If you read the documentation from the provided link, you'll learn some more.  I'll post a link to a similar question in a moment...

Comment: However, if you need to sort the objects by varying criteria, using a Comparator is better.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Agreed.  Implementing _Comparable_ is better if this is the defulat way to sort the object (ie the object's _natural order_).  If there are different ways that the object will get sorted, using a _Comparator_ is better.  I edited my answer to include both options.

Answer (score 2):

Use Collections.sort with a custom comparator.

```
eg.
public class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
        if (o1.getDistanceFromPlayer() > o2.getDistanceFromPlayer())
        {
           return 1;
        } 
        else if (o1.getDistanceFromPlayer() < o2.getDistanceFromPlayer())
        {
           return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then in your program, call

```
Collections.sort(YourArrayInstance, new DistanceComparator())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Custom Comparator` :

```
B = Collections.sort(A, new CustomComparator());

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<ClassA> {

    @Override
    public int compare(final ClassA a, final ClassA b) {
         //Make sure you check that neither a nor b are null..
         //..
         if (a.getDistanceFromPlayer() < b.getDistanceFromPlayer()) {
             return 1;
         } else if (a.getDistanceFromPlayer() > b.getDistanceFromPlayer()) {
             return -1;
         }
         return 0;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) your [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Main {
    public static class Player {
        private final float distance;

        public Player (final float position) {
            this.distance = position;           
        }

        public float getDistanceFrom () {
            return distance;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Player [distance=" + distance + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player> ();

        players.add (new Player (2));
        players.add (new Player (5));
        players.add (new Player (-3));
        players.add (new Player (1));

        Collections.sort(players, new Comparator<Player> () {
            @Override
            public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
                final float distance1 = o1.getDistanceFrom();
                final float distance2 = o2.getDistanceFrom();
                return (int) Math.signum (distance1 - distance2);
            }           
        });
        System.out.println(players);
    }
}
```

And a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/aTViJS) for it.

Comment: This is correct and valid.  However, sometimes I think it's easier for beginners to understand if the Comparator is implemented as a traditional class (rather than defining it inline).  I also don't see the benefit to using Math.signum (I've seen this a few times on this site).  Why not just return the difference (as an int)?

Comment: @jahroy You have tosomehow  convert the difference, which is a `float` to an `int`. You can't just make `(int) (a - b)` because of the way rounding works - you must use `Math.signum`.

Comment: Fair enough.  Now I understand.  You learn something every day at this site! For the record I already upvoted this answer.